# MongoDB query and select inner object

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I want to query for inner object and select only filtered inner objects from mongoddb document.

Consider below mongodb document.

```
{
  "schools": [
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": "ABC 1",
          "class": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "ABC 2",
          "class": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "ABC 3",
          "class": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "XYZ",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": "XYZ 1",
          "class": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "XYZ 2",
          "class": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to select only students in class 1. 
expected result json as below.

```
{
  "school": {
    "name": "ABC",
    "students": [
      {
        "name": "ABC 1",
        "class": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "ABC 3",
        "class": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "school": {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "students": [
      {
        "name": "XYZ 1",
        "class": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Even below result is fine with me.

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "ABC 1",
      "class": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "ABC 3",
      "class": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "XYZ 1",
      "class": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me to get this done. 
Really helpful if can provide mongodb query. 
I am using mongodb with spring data in my application.

Comment: `db.myCollection.find({"school.students.class":1});` Try

Comment: Is it array of school doc ?

Comment: If school is an object and there are multiple school objects, then it should be array of school objects ?

Comment: yes. i edited json accordingly. in initial question i was paste wrong json. now I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for mongo db array nested record search. The example code is here. [Document is here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

```
db.your_collection_name.find({'school.student.class':1})
```

If you only want students do flatmap for your results. [Here is document for flatmap in mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: yes. this is filtering my collection. but it return whole collection. i want only sublist from students.

Comment: I added documentation about selecting sublist from a list.

Comment: thanks for helping. . can you help me on use unwind with query to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could be able to find the query. 
First I have to unwind and apply matching criteria. this was work for me.

```
db.{mycollection}.aggregate(
    [
        { $unwind: '$schools.students'}, 
        { $match : { "schools.students.class" : 1 } }, 
        { $project : { "schools.name" : 1, 'schools.students' : 1 }  } 
    ] 
);
```